# Python, Pandas, drop a column that starts with \n

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem and I do not know how to solve it. I have columns that start with a line break in excel or may for some reason start with `\n` as provided in the example here.

[image]

How do I drop columns that start like that?

```
df_test = pd.read_excel(r'C:\...\test.xlsx')
df_test.drop("\nSomething")
```

Simply typing it out like that results in `KeyError: "['\\nSomething'] not found in axis"`.

Comment: `df_test.drop("\nSomething", axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_test.drop(r"\nSomething", axis=1)
```

The `r` stands for `raw` - it reads `'\n'` as `'\\n'`

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat backslashes as literal characters

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
for col in df:
    if col.startswith(r"\n"):
        df.drop(columns=[col], axis=1, inplace=True)
```